# Python Mocking: Not able to get the return value from mocked object

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write unit tests for this class using `pytest` & `unittest.mock`.

```
class GetDataStep:
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient

def execute(self, params: dict) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Executing Step: {self.__class__.__name__}")
    file_name = params["file_name"]
    storage_account_url = params["storage_account_url"]
    storage_account_key = params["storage_account_key"]
    container_name = params["container_name"]

    logging.info(f"Downloading {file_name}.")
    blob_service_client_instance = self.blob_service_client_instance(
        account_url=storage_account_url, credential=storage_account_key
    )

    blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(
        container_name, file_name, snapshot=None
    )

    try:
        blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
        data = blob_data.readall()
    except ResourceNotFoundError as rnfe:
        logging.info(f"Error: {file_name} does not exist!")
        logging.exception(rnfe)
        raise rnfe

    logging.info("File downloaded successfully")

    logging.info(f"Finished Step: {self.__class__.__name__}")
    return data.decode("utf-8")
```

I want to mock the behavior where the code is actually calling the azure services. So instead of querying the blob storage, I want to mock it and return a string value for testing.
This is my test function.

```
@patch("azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient")
def test_execute(mock_blob_service_client):
    
    get_data_step = steps.GetDataStep()

    # Define the input parameters
    params = {
        "file_name": "test_file.csv",
        "storage_account_url": "https://testaccount.blob.core.windows.net",
        "storage_account_key": "test_key",
        "container_name": "test_container",
    }

    # Define a mock blob client that will return the expected file data
    mock_blob_client = mock_blob_service_client.return_value.get_blob_client.return_value
    mock_blob_client.download_blob.readall.decode.return_value = "1,2,3\n4,5,6"

    get_data_step.blob_service_client_instance = mock_blob_service_client

    # Execute the step
    file_data = get_data_step.execute(params)

    # Verify that the BlobServiceClient was instantiated with the correct arguments
    mock_blob_service_client.assert_called_once_with(
        account_url="https://testaccount.blob.core.windows.net",
        credential="test_key"
    )

    
    mock_blob_service_client.return_value.get_blob_client.assert_called_once_with(
        params['container_name'], params['file_name'], snapshot=None
    )
    print(file_data)
    
    assert file_data == "1,2,3\n4,5,6"
```

The only problem is that the last assert statement is failing & giving me this error,

AssertionError: assert <MagicMockname='BlobServiceClient().get_blob_client().download_blob().readall().decode()' id='4851030480'> == '1,2,3\n4,5,6'

I am not able to find why it returns the mock object rather than the string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Comment: You need to add `return_value` for each function, I think that was the problem
`mock_blob_client.download_blob.return_value.readall.return_value.decode.return_value`